# How to can delay for open_node in jsTree?

Tags: javascript, jstree

I'm using jsTree and need a delay for opening the node only. How to do it?

I think that need to change anything here, but ...

```
.bind('changed.jstree', function(e, data) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.bind('changed.jstree', function(e, data) {
  setTimeout(300, /* your delay in ms*/, function() {
    // fn code goes here
  }
}
```